# How to insert rows into a SQL table with a SELECT NOT EXIST statement from one server to another?

Tags: ssis, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

My goal is to look on ID column in TableA -> ServerA and then if there are any new records that program could find in TableB -> ServerB that are not in TableA -> ServerA, insert those into TableA -> ServerA.

I have initialized an SSIS package to make this happen and then I'm planning to schedule that SSIS package with SQL Server Agent to run every one hour.

Now as a challenge, moving data between two servers, I had to create a linked server and then I was able to make a Select query to select all the data that are newly inserted into the table we're monitoring. I have trouble inserting those multiple rows into the table now.

Here is my SQL statement connected with Linked Server to get all the newly added values;

```
SELECT ID, trx_date, work_order, Department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hrs, job_start, job_end, qty_ordered, qty_produced, item_no, lot_no, default_bin, posted, wrapped, total_shift_hrs, check_emp, machine, operation_complete
FROM STLEDGSQL01.MES_DEV.dbo.wrap_labor AS SRC
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID, trx_date, work_order, Department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hrs, job_start, job_end, qty_ordered, qty_produced, item_no, lot_no, default_bin, posted, wrapped, total_shift_hrs, check_emp, machine, operation_complete
FROM wrap_labor_SSIS AS TGT WHERE (TGT.ID = SRC.ID)))
```

Following is my SSIS package and how I'm planning to run the Execute SQL Task function
[image]

Could someone help me here to get the SQL Query to INSERT those records which I'm SELECTING above?

I've tried the following with no luck;

```
INSERT INTO [MACOLA_TABLES_SQL01].[dbo].[wrap_labor_SSIS] VALUES (
SELECT ID, trx_date, work_order, Department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hrs, job_start, job_end, qty_ordered, qty_produced, item_no, lot_no, default_bin, posted, wrapped, total_shift_hrs, check_emp, machine, operation_complete
FROM STLEDGSQL01.MES_DEV.dbo.wrap_labor AS SRC
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID, trx_date, work_order, Department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hrs, job_start, job_end, qty_ordered, qty_produced, item_no, lot_no, default_bin, posted, wrapped, total_shift_hrs, check_emp, machine, operation_complete
FROM wrap_labor_SSIS AS TGT WHERE (TGT.ID = SRC.ID))))
```

I always try to make a `dbfiddle` for clear understanding of the SQL tables but in this situation with two servers it's not easy task for me to create one, but I will answer any questions/clarifications anyone need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before and the MERGE command works perfectly.

Basically:

```
MERGE target_table USING source_table
ON merge_condition
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN update_statement
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN insert_statement
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE;
```

There are lots of good tutorials on it's usage online, i.e. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/

Comment: Wow, did not even know there was a "MERGE" command exist. Thank you very much for helping me out. After going through the sql server tutorial I do believe this is the answer I was looking for. Will try it out. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: No problem.  I was amazed when I found it too - it's like magic!

Comment: BTW - there are MERGE script generators which will build the SQL for you, i.e. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/merge-statement-generator

Comment: Wow thank you much for this information too, just curious on one thing...have you ever done this MERGE on multiple servers? Cause I did create a 'linked server' on the other server and am writing this MERGE statement on there just to make sure MERGE can see/have access for both servers. But seems like it's not liking it?

Comment: I havent use linked servers for this, but it should work fine if they're both SQL servers. What issues are you having?